# DeMark Indicators

Tags: programming, technical-analysis

Would anyone know of a library in R that handles `DeMark`indicators. Just wanted to check-in with the community before I invested a whole lot of time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: DeMark is a pretty straightforward calculation if my memory serves me.  Might as well just write a few lines of code out yourself instead of scouring the web for a package to install...that's what I often do anyway...

Answer (score 1):

No, packages do not get constructed for proprietary measures, particularly ones that are not complex.  Rather, it is for general processes such as ARIMA or MCMC.